# how to make that two different objects have the same number of vertices

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, shape-keys, .fbx, motion-capture

I'm trying to **join as shapes** two objects that don't have **the same number of vertices**. The white shape is a **FBX** face object that come from the **brekel pro face 2** and it contains the shapekeys / joints captured by the **kinect 2**. The other shape is the head of a character that I've created by myself. It contains no shapekeys,because I want that the shapekeys of the white face are merged into it. So,I have selected first the white face and then I have shift selected the character's face and I did **"join as shapes"**,but the operation has not completed succesfully,because it said : **selected meshes must have the same number of vertices**. Is there a way to increase the number of vertices of the white face until that it has the same number of vertices of the character's face ? Or do you know another way to do that ? thanks.

[image: abc]

Comment: It won't work even if you get the vertex count to match. The vertex order, placement and topology is different so your shape key would be just random garble. Join as shapes is meant to transfer keys between identical base meshes. Look into using Shrinkwrap modifier on the empty mesh to conform to other mesh with each shapekey, then apply the shrinkwrap modifier to shapekey. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBvA2Hduk_w

Comment: If I give you my blender file,can you make a short tutorial ? it seems easy to do,but it isn't,at least for me...thanks.

Comment: You can practice with the shrinkwrap tutorial / other tutorials and try to make something with it to understand how it works. What you're trying to do with facial expression shapekey transfers here is not trivial.

Comment: please give me some other tutorial to follow.

Comment: plus,the empty mesh is the default character's face (it's my face),so I don't want that it conforms to the white mesh,but the reverse.

Comment: I need some help or advice. I use shape keys with a mirror modifier to make expressions for my model. But every time I apply the shape keys with the mirror modifier, I always end up with two more faces instead of one. I would be very happy with any help https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDZ2r.jpg